# Procedure to know how many points are there in the matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, point

I am wondering if there is any way in matlab which let me to know number of points in the plot ?! 
In other words, if I have `plot(x,y,'*');` and I want to know how many points `*` is there in this plot.

Thank you ..

Comment: -1 I don't agree with the initial up-vote. As it stands the question either isn't a real question or it is poorly worded (see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489270/procedure-to-know-how-many-points-are-there-in-the-matlab-plot/16489450#comment23668480_16489450))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This number is equal to the number of elements in y.

Comment: but my meaning was to create the matrix itself not to calculate the numbers only